# JSON prepare with .Net 2.0

Tags: .net, json, sanitization

I am limited to .Net 2.0 framework.  How can I replace all invalid characters in a string?  I am building a string array in JSON format and outputting it to the screen.

I tried using .Replace to get rid of the characters I know cause problems (like \n, \, [, ], {, }), but errors persist.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and ended up using [System.Net.Json](http://json.codeplex.com/).